# For Grad School Statement of Purpose, do I have to precisely state what research theme I'm interested in?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, statement-of-purpose

I am applying for a MSc research degree. So far, I haven't secured a supervisor, but I am interested mostly in cardiovascular research and there are only 3 of them in the entire department. 
Since they might not agree to take me (I've spoken to them), the program advisor suggested that I still apply anyway and hopefully some other PI will accept me (essentially I'll accept the offer to work in any other research theme as long as I get admitted to the program).

Then comes the statement of purpose, my friends in grad school recommended that I make it generic. However, a generic letter must still include my specific research interest, right? and If I were to write that I am solely interested in cardiovascular research, other PIs in the department may pass on me.

I googled and searched for how to write a proper statement of purpose but haven't found a clear answer to my question. From your experience, how long was your letter of intent and what exactly included ?

Comment: 2 pages. what it exactly included? A summary of my intellectual history, why I want to join and roughly what topics I would consider+names of possible advisors.

Comment: Precise?  Yes.  Accurate?  Not necessarily.

Comment: @JeffE could you elaborate on why it doesnt have to be necessarily accurate?